# Which pdf reader supports "Hand tool" in Ubuntu 16

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec

Which pdf reader for Ubuntu 16 supports "Hand tool", I tried FBreader, Document Viewer, but they do not provide Hand Tool.

Comment: Okular has a "Browse tool" whose pointer icon is a hand (it can be used to drag text around). Is that the one you are thinking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is shipped with at least two tools which offer "Hand tool" to work with PDF files out of the box:

1. **Firefox**. Pick the option from the menu.
   [image]
2. **Evince**. Middle mouse button allows to drag the document around:
   [image]